# Link to Shop-Filter with .current-menu-item

Tags: filters, woocommerce-offtopic

I’m having trouble adding the class .current-menu-item to a specific link. The link “Neue Schmuckstücke” links to “URL/alle?filter_kollektion=star-records&query_type_kategorie=or”. The Menu (marked in the Screenshot) is added with the WordPress menu (individual links). The link above “Alle Schmuckstücke” gets the .current-menu-item automatically – however “Neue Schmuckstücke” doesn’t get it automatically from WordPress. I guess it has to do with the WooCommerce GET-Link or AJAX or whatever (I’m not a programmer).

Now I’m looking for a solution to add the .current-menu-item class to that link when it’s active. The same way it works with “Alle Schmuckstücke”. Does anyone have a solution? Maybe add something to the funcions.php targeting the #menu-item-2344 to add the .current-menu-item class when active …?

Website:
http://www.luna.at/kollektion/

Screenshot:
[image]

HTML output:

```
<div class="menu-schmuck-container">
<ul id="menu-schmuck" class="menu">
<li id="menu-item-2343" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom current-menu-item menu-item-home menu-item-2343">
<a href="http://www.luna.at/kollektion/">Alle Schmuckstücke</a>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-2344" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-2344">
<a href="http://www.luna.at/kollektion/alle?filter_kollektion=star-records&query_type_kategorie=or">Neue Schmuckstücke</a>
</li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You could manually add CSS rules to achieve it, if the body (or any other parent element) has a specific class when on those different URLs

Comment: I've tried that, but no success. After not touching the website for 2 months it suddenly worked like a miracle ... and I don't know why.